# Masters table not found in database

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have an issue with laravel.

I have created a database named **billing** and connection is working fine for all tables. Now I created a new table named as masters. When I'm using this table then it is **showing error base table or view masters not found**

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the code hows you access the ```masters``` table?

Answer (score 1):

This is usual for beginners. I have a few hints:

- You might want to manually check the database, outside of Laravel, to
  be sure the table has not been add.
- Sometimes, you might just have misspelt the table name.
- Did you forget to run the migration? If so, you need to run the
  migration to add the table to the database. You can simple use `php
  artisan migrate` on the command line.
- If all these don't resolve it, dump you autoload files with composer and rerun your migration. You can use `composer dumpautoload` and then `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Answer (score 0):

To create a migration, use the `make:migration` Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_masters_table
```

The new migration will be placed in your `database/migrations` directory.

You can use Laravel schema builder to expressively create and modify tables.

To run all of your outstanding migrations, execute the migrate Artisan command: `php artisan migrate`